# Setting up Kibana timestamp equivalent to my log file's timestamp

Tags: logstash, kibana, kibana-4, logstash-grok

I am facing time matching issue in kibana. My log files have an older timestamp but when I parse the logfiles, the @timestamp picks up the current timestamp instead of the original time of the log file.

Here is an example of my logfile entry:

```
2015-12-25 17:39:45+0000 [SSHChannel session (0) on SSHServicessh-connection on HoneyPotTransport,21438,220.166.50.228] Closing TTYLog: log/tty/20151225-173944-319eb90f.log
```

I am using grok to match the timestamp using regex and storing it in `mytimestamp` field.

```
grok {

    match => ["message", "(?<mytimestamp>%{YEAR:year}-%{MONTHNUM:month}-%{MONTHDAY:day} %{TIME:time}%{ISO8601_TIMEZONE})"]
```

}

I am then matching with the date filter to make kibana use the log file timestamp.

```
#Matches with timestamp
    date {
            match => [ "mytimestamp" , "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
        }
```

I read some of the older questions on stackoverflow and tried to solve my problem based on them but I guess I am missing some key thing in this.

Answer (score 0):

Your date filter is wrong. mytimestamp contains a timezone. So date filter should be:

```
date {
    match => [ "mytimestamp" , "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ" ] # <= Z must be added
}
```